# Multiple entrypoints in typescript external modules not resolved

Tags: typescript, npm

I am trying to build an external module, `@example/lib` for TypeScript with multiple entry points.  I would like to consume it something like this:

```
import * as lib from '@example/lib';
import * as foobar from '@example/lib/foobar';
```

I can build an npm module which works correctly by setting `"target": "es5"` and `"declaration": true` in my tsconfig, and pointing my `"main"` and `"typings"` properties in the `package.json` to a single source location.  If I do this, I can always import `@example/lib` without issue.

The problem arises when I attempt to import `@example/lib/foobar`.  TypeScript complains that it "Cannot find module `@example/lib/foobar`".  The compiled output, however can import this submodule perfectly fine (after being processed by webpack).

Inside my `@example/lib` project I have the source files:

```
index.js
index.d.ts
foobar.js
foobar.d.ts
```

And in my package.json I have:

```
{
    ...
    "typings": "index.d.ts"
    "main": "index.js"
    ...
}
```

What do I need to do to keep TypeScript happy (and type checking!) in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above does, in fact work.

Unfortunately in my case the d.ts file was not being generated for foobar, (though the source was, due to an error).

Comment: I seem to have the same problem. Would be grateful if you could elaborate on what your error was and how you solved it.

Comment: My apologies, it's been a while so the full details are a bit rough- but the issue is that the d.ts file for @example/lib/foobar was not being generated when I compiled that module to be installed alongside my project. I needed to tell typescript to produce this file when compiling my foobar project, as well as add  the property  "types": "./foobar.d.ts" to the package.json of the published npm module @example/foobar. I hope this helps.